# functions executed before angular http success response

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-http

Am trying to hit web service with a directive controller, I hit the post method and got the response, but values I expected are become empty because all compiled before the success response.
This is my controller within the directive

```
controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'popupService','SessionUtils', function($scope, $http, popupService,SessionUtils) {
                $scope.responseValue = "";
                  $scope.sendCSVFile = function(link, fileData) {
                    $scope.seriveResponse = $http({
                      method: "POST",
                      url: link,
                      data: fileData,
                      headers: {
                        'Content-Type': undefined
                      }
                    }).success(function(response) {
                        if(response.status == "FAILURE"){
                            popupService.showErrMsg(response.message);
                            return false;
                        }
                        else {
                            $scope.responseValue = response;
                            //SessionUtils.updateResponse(response);
                            var success = "File Uploaded Successfully";
                            popupService.showSuccessMsg(success);
                            return response;
                        }
                        return $scope.responseValue = response;
                    });

                    });
```

and I called the controller from the directive link function like

```
var res = scope.sendCSVFile(attrs.getUrlModel, formData); 
scope.gridUpdate(res);
```

the value `res` returning undefined, but I get the response after I binded the `res`. How to I get the promising response and execute the function after.!

Answer (score 0):

You can get promise, not standard data, ajax is asynchronous call, so change code to:

```
$scope.sendCSVFile = function(link, fileData) {
                return $http({ //return promise object
                  method: "POST",
                  url: link,
                  data: fileData,
                  headers: {
                    'Content-Type': undefined
                  }
                }).success(function(response) {
                    if(response.status == "FAILURE"){
                        popupService.showErrMsg(response.message);
                        return false;
                    }
                    else {
                        $scope.responseValue = response;
                        //SessionUtils.updateResponse(response);
                        var success = "File Uploaded Successfully";
                        popupService.showSuccessMsg(success);
                        return response;
                    }
                    return $scope.responseValue = response;
                });

                });
```

usage:

```
$scope.sendCSVFile(attrs.getUrlModel, formData).then(function(response){

    //here ajax is completed and in response variable You have raturn from success callback
    if (response)
    scope.gridUpdate(response);
});
```

Comment: But the problem is `scope.sendCSVFile` is in directve link function

Comment: OK so how You used it before in this way - var res = scope.sendCSVFile(attrs.getUrlModel, formData); 
scope.gridUpdate(res); ?

Comment: returning like this `scope.gridUpdate({response});` but promising response I got in response but HTML it showing undefined

Comment: @VivekVikranth add this part of code, update question.